# Run 2 Windows XP modes?

Tags: windows-xp-mode

I have a Windows XP Virtual PC installed, which I have modified slightly. How do I install another copy to run in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a second instance of the XP mode virtual machine by basing it on the same base image as that of the instance created by the installer.

There's a good [blog post here](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/) that walks through the process (in this case, the author is creating the second VM in order to run IE 6, 7 and 8 side-by-side).

**EDIT**: I should also point out that this process can be used as many times as you like, so you can create more than two copies should you wish to.